# POST data to aspx from PHP and get output

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net

I want to scrape some data from an aspx page.

The page consists of a calendar and on the selection of the date, you see a list of actions from that date.

I want to use a PHP script to automatically select a different date each day and then get the content(file_get_contents?!) and parse it as I desire.

But i have the following problem:

- the page is domain.tld/name.aspx

each date on the calendar is a link with

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$B_Center$Name1$Name2','****')
```

After I select the date, the page does a refresh, the URL remains domain.tld/name.aspx and shows the list from that date.

I have virtually no experience with ASPX, so I need some help. I've used firebug and developer tools to try and understand the POST but it's much different from PHP or I just dont understand it.

I want to somehow sent that post to that page and get it's output, but I dont know how, can I use an URL like:

domain.tld/name.aspx?smth=X&other=Y ?

But what variable do I use?

The FORM data has:

```
__ASYNCPOST=true
__EVENTARGUMENT=***
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$B_Center$Name1$Name2
__LASTFOCUS=
__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0
__SCROLLPOSITIONY=0
__VIEWSTATE=random data
__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=
ctl00$B_Center$Name1$Search=
ctl00$B_Center$Name1$chkPaginare=on
ctl00$B_Center$Name1$drpMonthCal=11
ctl00$B_Center$Name1$drpYearCal=2015
ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager1=ctl00$B_Center$Name1$Name2|ctl00$B_Center$Name1len1$Name2
```

Can you somehow point to the right direction or help with a script that can get me that output?

Thx,
R.